# Sum a custom field that has a shortcode in it

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called "subjects" it has a custom field called "exams_count"
that custom field value is a shortcode that another plugins uses, when the custom field is displayed it show a numerical value lets say 10 or something
but the data in the field itself is the shortcode as  I mentioned above
my quesiton is: I want to sum all the displayed value of that custom field after the shortcode is executed 
how can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying you need to do it after the php has been run? If so that would likely need JS.

Comment: yup exactly! after the shortcode php has been run and it returned the values I would like to sum all the results it gave

Comment: If you did it post PHP executing, you could do it on document ready with JS based on the field names, but this would leave you with some degree of it not updating immediately. Can you post your rendered HTML, and possibly some more information about the plugin?

Comment: I don't really care about it updating immediately since the data will be changed once a month or so, I don't have html now since I am trying to solve the programming issue first, I had to resolve to this solution as a last resort after many other restrictions in the plugin : TablePress

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383772/sum-value-of-elements-inside-of-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code it's a bit difficult, so bear with me.

Can you do this:

```
$x=0;

$x=do_shortcode ('[your_shortcode]');  // say its 10

$valuetoadd = 20; //for example

$exams_count_sum= $x + $valuetoadd;

echo $exams_count_sum;  //should equal 30
```

Or, if you are in a loop, this could be a good starting point:

```
$examtotal=0;   
$examtotal_sum=0;            
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        the_content();
        $examtotal=do_shortcode ('[your_shortcode]');
        $examtotal_sum = $examtotal_sum + $examtotal;
    endwhile;
        echo 'total is '.$examtotal_sum;  //this will be your total
```

Comment: the shortcode is something like that 
`[table-info id=123 field=number_rows format=raw /]`

what I am trying to do is sum the custom field called exams_count in  the whole custom post type called " subjects " then display the result of it